# Google Cloud Firestore Transactions and Batches

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Can we write batch inside a transaction in google cloud functions to access documents stored in cloud firestore? I tried using two transactions in cloud functions.

Comment: Can you make your question little more clear, specify coding language &  a brief on what you are trying to do

Comment: I don't see any restrictions on this. Are you getting any errors?